# Compute expectation value of an operator in openfermion

Tags: openfermion

I am trying to compute the 2-electron reduced-density matrix (2-RDM) for a given quantum state with openfermion. The code is as follow

```
two_rdm = np.zeros((n_qubits,) * 4, dtype=complex)
psi =  = openfermion.haar_random_vector(2 ** n_qubits, random_seed).astype(numpy.complex64)
for i, j, k, l in itertools.product(range(n_qubits), repeat=4):
    transformed_operator = jordan_wigner(
            FermionOperator(((i, 1), (j, 1), (k, 0), (l, 0))))
    two_rdm[i, j, k, l] = openfermion.linalg.expectation(transformed_operator, psi)
```

The problem is with the last line, which gives the following exception

```
TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "ABCMeta") to str
```

After examning the source code, I figured out that the problem is with the `[operator * state][1]`. Can anybody help to fix this?

Comment: I think one would need more information in order to answer this question. Which line is throwing that exception? What sort of object is `converter`? You mention the package `openfermion`, but it looks like you're actually using Qiskit Nature?

Comment: If I had to guess, I'd say the normalization error you see is related to `init_state`. But it's hard to diagnose without a minimal working example: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the openfermion documentation ([see here](https://quantumai.google/reference/python/openfermion/linalg/expectation)), it says the operator must be a `scipy.sparse` matrix. So, replacing `transformed_operator` with `get_sparse_matrix(transformed_operator, n_qubits=n_qubits)` in the final line will give you a `2**n_qubits x 2**n_qubits` dimensional sparse matrix, which should remove the error.

Comment: After the modification, the program output the exception `dimension mismatch` for the state to multiply the operator.

Comment: I've edited my answer to something that should fix that problem. In `get_sparse_matrix` there is an optional argument `n_qubits` to specify the number of qubits you are working with.

Comment: Thanks for the answers. That really helps to fix the problem! I have one question about the quantum state of openfermion. The state is a $2^n$-length vector. I want to know what is the ordering of the vector. The first one, state[0] should be '0000' for a 4-qubit state. Then, is '1000' or '0001' the state[1]?

Comment: Also, there seems have problems when the state is a density matrix after adding deplorizing noisy to the circuit. Each expectation will go to zero in this case.